# How do I read / write gzipped files in C++?

Tags: c++, gzip, zlib, gzipstream

How do I read / write gzipped files in C++?

The `iostream` wrapper classes [here](http://www-d0.fnal.gov/d0dist/dist/packages/lm_access/devel/lm_access/gzstream.hpp) look good, and here is a simple usage example:

```
gz::igzstream in(filename);
std::string line;
while(std::getline(in, line)){
  std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

But I wasn't able to actually link it (although I have a `/usr/lib/libz.a`). A simple

```
g++ test-gzstream.cpp -lz
```

didn't do it (`undefined reference to gz::gzstreambase::~gzstreambase()`).

Comment: So you need to use igzstream and find the problem or any solution is ok?

Comment: LGPL is not an option to me, since I'm developing for iOS, do you know of a non-viral alternative?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Obviously you need the cpp-file where the gzstreambase destructor is defined as well, i.e. [gzstream.cpp](http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/compgeom/gzstream/#inst) (that's the link fault). libz is just a c-api for gzip, it knows nothing of c++ stdlib streams.

Boost's iostream lib has gzip and bzip2 streams too.

EDIT: Updated the link to point to the latest version of the code that includes a major bug fix.

Comment: he uses lib instead of .cpp file.

Comment: Then he needs to link to the lib where gzstream.cpp has been compiled. liblm_access?

Comment: gzstream  is LGPL licensed. careful not to use as static library if closed source.

Answer (score 16):

Consider using the Boost zip filters. According to them, it supports `bzip`, `gzip` and `zlib` format.

- [boost zlib](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/zlib.html)
- [boost gzip](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html)
- [boost bzip2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/bzip2.html)

Answer (score 15):

To give more details than what was briefly mentioned by the other users, here is how I managed to work with `gzstream` on my computer.

First, I downloaded `gzstream` and installed it in my home (the two last lines can be added to your `~/.bash_profile`):

```
cd ~/src
mkdir GZSTREAM
cd GZSTREAM/
wget http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/compgeom/gzstream/gzstream.tgz
tar xzvf gzstream.tgz
cd gzstream
make
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/src/GZSTREAM/gzstream
export LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/src/GZSTREAM/gzstream
```

Then, I tested the installation:

```
make test
...
# *** O.K. Test finished successfully. ***
```

Finally, I wrote a dummy program to check that I could effectively use the library:

```c
cd ~/temp
vim test.cpp
```

Here is the code (very minimalist, should be much improved for real applications!):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <gzstream.h>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
  cout << "START" << endl;

  igzstream in(argv[1]);
  string line;
  while (getline(in, line))
  {
    cout << line << endl;
  }

  cout << "END" << endl;
}
```

Here is how I compiled it:

```
gcc -Wall test.cpp -lstdc++ -lgzstream -lz
```

And last but not least, here is how I used it:

```
ls ~/ | gzip > input.gz
./a.out input.gz
START
bin/
src/
temp/
work/
END
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this trouble as well with old GCC compiler. I just fixed this by making a header only version of gzstream which should be easier to use.

https://gist.github.com/1508048

Answer (score 1):

This is from the "Gzstream Library Home Page"

> Either compile gzstream.C by hand,
>   place it in some library, and move
>   gzstream.h into the include search
>   path of your compiler. Or use the
>   provided Makefile, adapt its
>   variables, and follow the remarks in
>   the Makefile.