# How to compress a .json file into .json.gz file format in c++?

Tags: gzip

I compressed a json string in gzipped format.
But I want to compress a **.json** file into **.json.gz** file format.
How can I do that in c++?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read / write gzipped files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624250/how-do-i-read-write-gzipped-files-in-c)

Comment: I don't think so. I don't need to read/write gzip files rather need to convert a file into .gz file format. Also I can't use boost gzip .

Comment: Converting it to .gz format _is_ reading in the json and writing it back out as a gzipped file. So the linked answer is highly relevant.

Comment: @MarkAdler I got it. For this I will need to use gzstream library. But I cant use external library. Is there any way to do that with c++ std library?

Comment: Sure. Just copy the source code from [zlib](https://zlib.net/) into your program.

Answer (score 0):

I could compress a file into .gz file in cpp that I needed.
Used linux terminal command for file gzip

```
char Command[] = "gzip filepath/filename.json";
```

Then executed the command in code by using

```
int sysRet = system(Command);
```

Then in device storage desired filepath `filename.json.gz` file will be created.